# what kind of information is shared between entangled particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, wave-particle-duality

when two entangled particles are separate by distance . what exactly happens to them , that influence us to consider they connected each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No information is transmitted between particles due to their entanglement.  Rather, entangled particles have related histories.  This would mean that they carry "hidden variables", except that the histories themselves are indeterminate.  Measure one particle of an entangled pair, and you effectively select (at random) one of the possible histories.  Because the particles share their history, with that measurement you have also selected the *same* history of the other particle.

Comment: Histories refers what

Comment: Ya explanation was brilliant but it would be better if you use some example

Comment: Your **history** and mine were effectively independent until I read your comment. Because I read your comment a few minutes ago, my  life path is altered; and a complete *causal* description of my history (my path up until *now*, which is a few minutes after I read your comment) can't be made without including *your* history up to the moment you posted your comment.  If you flipped a quantum coin to decide whether or not to post the comment, the flip would result in two divergent combined life paths; and in each path your experiences and mine would be correlated.  Our paths would be entangled.

Comment: Please use any microscopic particles to explain this situation.

Comment: When a photon is converted to two photons each with half the frequency of the original, the two new photons are entangled.  The history of each new photon includes the event at which both new photons were created.   This paper describes a couple of methods for producing entangled photons via "SPDC" :[https://www.pdx.edu/nanogroup/sites/www.pdx.edu.nanogroup/files/Jesse%20L.%20Catalano%2C%20Spontaneous%20Parametric%20Down-Conversion%20and%20Quantum%20Entanglement.pdf]

Comment: link that you had given was exteamly helpfull

Comment: Glad to know it.  If you got the information you need, you can click on the check mark at the left of the answer.

Comment: can you give any means of source that i can contact you, any watsup or somthing

Comment: Yes: come to [https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85959/photon-forge]

Comment: its too complicated , how can i meet you there , in stack chat

Comment: Have you tried?  It won't be realtime; but it is a chat room.

Comment: no sorry , i have some real question with me. i am not here to dispoint you

Comment: is there process that i need to do after entering in that stack chat .

Comment: how can i get you there

Comment: so that i can clear my douts

Comment: You should be able to get there simply by clicking on the link

Comment: Alternatively, click on "chat" on the e SE page and search for "photon forge".

Comment: yes i did it , but it is asking your response , accept my request sir then i be there

Comment: when will you be free

Comment: is there any source other than,this chat site . i have very less points . please i need your help